# How to rebase two branches with git?

Tags: git

I am trying to rebase master into dev:

```
git rebase master
```

Then I get : Current branch is up to date.

However when I check the difference between the two branches I get a conflict. Why does git not say something like conflict detected or something?

See also here for a code [sample](https://github.com/dimitri-a/gitje)

Comment: It is because dev branch already has commit 5bc2e51138f6827c6654e468a05b875e3c81edf3 from master(the only commit in master). Its in sync with master or you could say ahead of master by 1 commit and hence the message.

Comment: What do you mean by "check the difference between the two branches"?

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to merge the branch **dev** into **master** in a way that show just one commit with a single comment you need to add the option --interactive.
So the command you run from **dev** branch  become:

```
git rebase master --interactive
```

In this way you can **squash** the commits that you want to hide.

So, for example, when you get this code back:

```
pick 01d1124 Adding the book add function
pick 6340aaa Creating the unit test for book add function
pick ebfd367 Now the function is finished
# Rebase 60709da..30e0ccb onto 60709da
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

You edit the code like this:

```
pick 01d1124 Adding the book delete function
squash 6340aaa Creating the unit test for book add function
squash ebfd367 Now the function is finished
```

Then you put a # before all the comments that you want to hide.

```
# This is a combination of 4 commits.
# The first commit's message is:
Adding the book delete function
# This is the 2nd commit message:
# Creating the unit test for book add function
# This is the 3rd commit message:
# Now the function is finished
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Explicit paths specified without -i nor -o; assuming --only paths...
# Not currently on any branch.
```

Then you checkout **master** and then

```
git merge dev
```

In this way you have merged the branch dev into master with just one commit.

---

Why you get **"Current branch is up to date" message.**?

You use git rebase you want to update the branch **dev** with the commits that has been done on the branch **master** after the moment when **dev** has been instantiated from master.
When on the branch *dev** you do:

```
git rebase master
```

If you didn’t do any new commit on master after that moment you get the message:
"Current branch is up to date."

This because at a lower level, what rebase actually does is to pluck one by one the new commits that has been done on the master branch and re-attach them to the last commit of dev.

So if you are not squashing any commit the command is unuseful.

I found very useful the images included in this article to understand the mechanism:
https://hackernoon.com/git-merge-vs-rebase-whats-the-diff-76413c117333

Answer (score -2):

I can't make a comment to your question so this may not answer all your questions.

1) Your rebase command works as expected. You're on a dev branch which has one commit above the master. It's already up-to-date and nothing to rebase there.

2) Not too sure what you meant by saying you see a conflict between two branches. However, I assume that you may want to deploy your changes from dev to master branch. If it's, here are steps:

```
git checkout master       // Switch the current branch to master
git merge dev             // Merge the dev branch to master (it will be just fast-forward)
git push origin master    // Push to origin
```

Now master and dev branches should stay at the same commit.

Comment: Because there is a conflict between the two I was expection a message in the rebase? There is one when you do a merge something like conflict between branches etc. Should there not be 1 for the rebase?

Comment: Both merge and rebase can cause conflicts if you have new commit(s) and identical line change from the branch you're rebasing with (master branch in your case). Your master branch is behind the dev and there are no new commits on it, therefore no conflicts for the rebase operation.

Comment: It would be really nice if the person who downvoted this answer could explain the legitimate reason. This will help me to improve my answer next time.